What is the difference between buying a future on a stock for 1Y vs buying two 6M contracts in a row?
Consider two positions.

Buy a 1Y future on SPX index.
Buy one 6M SPX future today, and roll it into another 6M future after the first one expires. Assume the 6 month funding rate is static across time, and the profit after 6 months is put into a bank account so it earns the funding rate.

My question is purely intuitively, why would these two approaches give different returns, and when is one preferred over the other?

All else being equal, you should be indifferent. However by choosing to roll at 6m instead of buying the 1 year contract, you expose yourself to interest rate risk if the interest rate curve shifts between the 6m and 1y mark.

Let's say the 6M funding rate is really low (say, 1%) and the 12M funding rate is really high (say, 10%).
Isn't it better to go with the 2nd approach then? By going with 2x6M, my futures price will only go up by 1% each time. If I go with the 1Y approach, my future price scales with 10%?.

No. In this scenario, that would mean that between 6m and 12m, the interest rate is expected to increase significantly (to approx 9.45%). When you go to roll after the 6m period, if nothing has changed, you will find that the cost of rolling should be around 4.6%.

if nothing has changed, the 6M funding rate 6 months from now should be equal to the 6M funding rate today, i.e. 1% in both cases.
